# Generating jmeter results into graphs off several trials through Hudson

Tags: hudson, jmeter

I'm in the process of integrating test scripts into a Continuous Integration system like Hudson. My goal is to benchmark each load test over time and display it in readable charts.

While there are plugins to generate graphs for a single script run, I'd like to know how each session's data, such as those found in the summary report, could be recorded over time.

One way would be to store the summary reports into a jtl file, and graph data off of that.

I've checked out the Performance Plugin for Hudson, but I'm at a block at how to modify the plugin to display more charts with more information.

Answer (score 2):

Both the reports from either JMeter or the Hudson plugin are snapshots (not charts over long periods of time) and that's part of the issue.  I went through this same exercise a few months back and decided to go with a solution that was better suited for this problem.

I setup [Logstash](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/) to pull the JMeter test results from the files it generates during every test.  It outputs those results into an [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elasticsearch/) index which I can chart with [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/).

I know this adds several new pieces of software into your setup, but it only took a day to set things up and the results are much better than what the performance plugin was able to provide.